# Why doesn't 'typeof' narrow a union type when the type of a property is a discriminant?

Tags: typescript, type-inference, discriminated-union, union-types, narrowing

If the members of a union type share a property, and the type of that property can be used to discriminate between those members, I should be able to narrow the type within an `if` clause using `typeof` as a condition. But it doesn't work.

For example, within the `if` clause below, the type of `event` should be inferred as `UserTextEvent` and the type of `event.target` should be inferred as `HTMLInputElement`:

```
type UserTextEvent = { value: string, target: HTMLInputElement };
type UserMouseEvent = { value: [number, number], target: HTMLElement };

type UserEvent = UserTextEvent | UserMouseEvent 


function handle(event: UserEvent) {
  if (typeof event.value === 'string') {
    event.value  // string, as expected

    event.target // should be narrowed to HTMLInputElement, but
                 // is still HTMLInputElement | HTMLElement. Why?
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess that's because `UserEvent` gets computed as `{ value: string | [number, number], target: HTMLInputElement | HTMLElement }` and loses its references to the original types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Typescript *discriminated unions* (currently) only support property *values* as discriminants, not property *types*.

Here are the types of discriminant properties supported [when discriminated unions support was added in Typescript 2.0](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/9163):

> A discriminant property type guard is an expression of the form `x.p == v`, `x.p === v`, `x.p != v`, or `x.p !== v`, where `p` and `v` are a property and an expression of a string literal type or a union of string literal types. The discriminant property type guard narrows the type of x to those constituent types of x that have a discriminant property p with one of the possible values of v.
>
> Note that we currently only support discriminant properties of string literal types. We intend to later add support for boolean and numeric literal types.

[Typescript 3.2 expanded that support](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html#non-unit-types-as-union-discriminants):

> Common properties of unions are now considered discriminants as long as they contain some singleton type (e.g. a string literal, null, or undefined), and they contain no generics.
>
> As a result, TypeScript 3.2 considers the error property in the following example to be a discriminant, whereas before it wouldn’t since Error isn’t a singleton type. Thanks to this, narrowing works correctly in the body of the unwrap function.
>
> ```
> type Result<T> = { error: Error; data: null } | { error: null; data: T };
> function unwrap<T>(result: Result<T>) {
>   if (result.error) {
>     // Here 'error' is non-null
>     throw result.error;
>   }
>   // Now 'data' is non-null
>   return result.data;
> }
> ```

[Typescript 4.5 added support for "Template String Types as Discriminants"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#template-string-types-as-discriminants).

> TypeScript 4.5 now can narrow values that have template string types, and also recognizes template string types as discriminants.
>
> As an example, the following used to fail, but now successfully type-checks in TypeScript 4.5.
>
> ```
> export interface Success {
>     type: `${string}Success`;
>     body: string;
> }
>  
> export interface Error {
>     type: `${string}Error`;
>     message: string
> }
>  
> export function handler(r: Success | Error) {
>     if (r.type === "HttpSuccess") {
>         const token = r.body;
>                      
> (parameter) r: Success
>     }
> }Try
> ```

In all cases, it's the *value* of the discriminant property that is used to discriminate, not its *type*.

In other words, as of the current version of Typescript, 4.5, you're out of luck. It's just not supported (yet). Here are the relevant open issues:

- [Union not narrowed with `typeof x.y` as a discriminant](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32399) (#32399)
- [Nested Tagged Unions](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18758) (#18758)
- [Type guard should infer the type of parent object when applied on a property](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384) (#42384)

Here is [a comment from Typescript dev team lead Ryan Cavanaugh](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/38839#issuecomment-1160929515):

> From the looks of it, this feature is unfortunately much more complex to implement than we had anticipated, and we don't think that the cost/benefit ratio is good in this case. As much as we want to support this pattern, the implications of these changes feel too far-reaching (even if they're necessary to actually support the scenario). We'll leave the original issue open in case later on down the line a simpler method of approach becomes available, but we aren't comfortable with introducing this much complexity in a critical codepath right now.

Answer (score 0):

You could somewhat rehydrate the original types with a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates):

```
interface UserTextEvent { value: string, target: HTMLInputElement };
interface UserMouseEvent { value: [number, number], target: HTMLElement };

type UserEvent = UserTextEvent | UserMouseEvent 


function handle(event: UserEvent) {
  if (isUserTextEvent(event)) {
    event.value  // string
                 //---------------------------------------------------------------
    event.target // HTMLInputElement
                 //
    return
  } else {
      event.value // [number, number]

      event.target // HTMLElement
  }


}

function isUserTextEvent(userEvent: UserEvent): userEvent is UserTextEvent {
    return typeof userEvent === 'string';
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=42&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdoBUIA8wCiAbhOMgN7JFwA2ArhAFzLphSgDmANMmHFBwhhmACSwBZADIBJEAAc6hGhAC2pMMgC%20AbgCwAKFCRYiFBmjiA9nUzF1FKrQbMA2iDoqARtB7uv0AF0ePgEhUQlJAmU1Mh0DAzAATzkzTCg7MgBeNDScfAyNAB8ci2tbEjJ4-QMYOhAEMGBLEGQACzgQABNlAAoICuES9IGASgoDZGRgGGQe4HRzKDzCAb7RsfIJyeR%209QA6anoUZAB6E5Y2Ti3tm9vts4BaJ%20eX17f3j8%20vj%20udgb2QoINGdkGIpLIFEpVPZimDItF7J5FMgQJYNHCIYootDwDwAO6tRLIAD8vzu5LOvygQjoUBAW00OxomHG%20juu3ABycKBBbg83igvn5gSq7P%20gKEp3OcOxMTADKqBk0VVq9UazSmC1yeBW6h6NmgBWYiwKI2YBuG9nmQ2WBVZN2pYFpLSSKUsMwtdsy3uQAHJWOwQBxfXp9JogA)

Comment: I'm pretty sure your first claim is wrong! It's a union of types, not of members.

Comment: Yes it's wrong, I've removed it. I don't have the actual explanation yet

Comment: i think I found the explanation.